# pip install numpy - doesn't install numpy on ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy

I'm having a blank brand spanking new aws ec2 container and trying to install pip in a virtual environment.

The only issue is, it says installation successful, but no numpy found

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-209 ~]$ virtualenv -p python36 env
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python36
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/ec2-user/env/bin/python36
Not overwriting existing python script /home/ec2-user/env/bin/python (you must use /home/ec2-user/env/bin/python36)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-209 ~]$ source ./env/bin/activate
(env) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-209 ~]$
(env) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-209 ~]$ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/90/ca61e203e0080a8cef7ac21eca199829fa8d997f7c4da3e985b49d0a107d/numpy-1.14.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
ccxt 1.11.149 requires aiohttp==3.0.1; python_version >= "3.5.3", which is not installed.
ccxt 1.11.149 requires cchardet==2.1.1; python_version >= "3.5.3", which is not installed.
ccxt 1.11.149 requires yarl==1.1.0; python_version >= "3.5.3", which is not installed.
aiodns 1.1.1 requires pycares>=1.0.0, which is not installed.
ccxt 1.11.149 has requirement setuptools==38.5.1, but you'll have setuptools 39.1.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.3
(env) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-209 ~]$  python -c "import numpy; numpy.show_config()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
(env) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-40-209 ~]$
```

Does anybody have any idea what the issue is?

machine details:

aws nano
512MB Ram
1024MB Swap
8GB Storage
AWS linux

Comment: What is `python --version` ?

Comment: 3.6, but the issue is that line:

Successfully installed numpy-1.14.3

and next line says

python -c "import numpy; numpy.show_config()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

it works without issues outside the venv

Comment: This may be related to installing/running different versions of python and pip. What are the results of `which pip` and `which python` while virtualenv is activated?